# Prometheus how to use multiple labels

Tags: prometheus

I have multiple crawls, how do I aggregate these results，Below is my example：

`{data="eth0",direction="sum",instance="localhost:21081",job="etha"} 111476
{data="eth0",direction="sum",instance="localhost:21082",job="etha"} 29163
{data="eth0",direction="sum",instance="localhost:21084",job="etha"} 10439`

I use the following statement, but no effect：

```
sum_over_time(eth0{data="eth0",direction="sum",job="eth0"}[20m])
```

Still there are multiple lines, I hope to be able to aggregate into one line

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the following command?

```
sum (rate (sum_over_time{data="eth0",direction="sum",job="eth0"}[20m]))
```

If you want to sum it based on a field uniquely e.g. data="eth0" can have multiple value, use the following command:

```
sum (rate (sum_over_time{data="eth0",direction="sum",job="eth0"}[20m])) by (data)
```

Comment: I am a combination of multiple instances of indicators, not an instance